# In Wordpress SQL database, where does it show which attachment(s) has been assigned to which post?

Tags: sql, wordpress

I was able to tap into my wordpress database and pull all the rows from the "wp_posts" table with "post_type=post" and display the content on another page (not wordpress, just built from scratch). The problem I have is the images (in the database "attachments") are in the same table with "post_type=attachment". So I cannot pull the correct images into my site. I can't find how they are related to the posts. I thought "wp_term_relationships" was my answer but those are just category relationships. In short, Where are the image relationships?

Comment: Ok, I also noticed the "post_parent" column in the wp_posts table. I see that the value stored there does correspond to the post ID of the post that was being edited when I uploaded the picutre. But what if I upload a bunch of pictures all at once, they will all be assigned to the same post or if I upload a bunch without writing a post (just through the media gallery) they don't have a post_parent. Even if I add it to a post later. The value is still 0.

Comment: What do you want to do exactly?